# Aspect fill blurry view

Tags: swift

I created some pageController which is working but with one problem. I have background image and I've added blurry view to it. But it doesn't stretch with the image:

[image]

The way I created the blurry view is this:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = self.view.frame

        self.view.insertSubview(blurEffectView, at: 1)
```

I have tried to make image to aspect fill, aspect fit etc.. Nothing works.

Answer (score 3):

You have to constrain the blur effect view to the image view, just as you would with any kind of view.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.insertSubview(blurEffectView, at: 1)
```

Comment: This still won't resize the blurred view if `self.view`'s size changes, as it's guaranteed to do when the user rotates the device.

Comment: And this answer is *identical* to what OP posted!